# Can a kangaroo jump higher than/above the building?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

A building cannot jump. We generally use "higher" to campare with something that can jump. But, can we use "higher" in this context?
It comes from the following joke -
Q. Can a kangaroo jump higher than the Empire State building?
A. Yes, cause the Empire State building cannot jump.
If I used "above the Empire State building", the question would be straightforward and wouldn't be meant for joke.

Comment: San, it's **extremely commonplace** in English that English is highly ambiguous.  It's an absolutely basic part of the language. It would be like pointing out that McDonalds sells hamburgers, you know?

Comment: Nitpick: The answer should probably either use "because" or should indicate that the informal (mostly spoken) contraction is intended by writing it as "'cause".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Can a kangaroo jump higher than the Empire State building?" is correct English. The point of the joke is that it has (potentially) two meanings.

Answer (score 0):

Can a Kangroo jump higher than a building?
Answer-Yes
Because a building can not jump but the kangroo can jump that is why the Kangroo can jump higher
What were your thoughts?
Answer-You were thinking that can a Kangroo jump over the building that is why you were tricked!

Comment: Your answer is simply incomprehensible. Please edit.